# Youtube API create playlist and embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

**Description:**

Using Javascript, I populate a YouTube link with video IDs that the user has selected, and end up with a URL like the following:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?video_ids=0vrdgDdPApQ,cbut2K6zvJY

Visiting the above link, YouTube creates a list for those videos and returns you to it:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vrdgDdPApQ&list=TLQJeFf9I5pC0yMTA4MjAxNQ

And of course, it is possible to embed the second link by simply replacing the /watch URL with /embed.

**My question(s):**

Is it possible to embed the first link (/watch_videos) somehow?
If not, is it possible to create a YouTube playlist client side (maybe using the YouTube API) and then embed it? (Other implementations / ideas are more than welcome)

If neither of the above, is it then possible to "chain" YouTube video IDs to an embeded player and play them successively (JavaScript / YouTube API)?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can embed the first video then in the playlist parameter add other selected Ids

For ex:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/0vrdgDdPApQ?playlist=cbut2K6zvJY,7iw30sK2UCo,sYV5MTy0v1I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked as intended. I had only tried to embed the first video and then add the rest to a ?list= parameter rather than ?playlist= as I couldn't find any documentation on this.